# In xml, why in some case do we use <tag content/> and in some cases we use <tag>content<tag/>?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

Coming from web development for every `<tag>` there should be a closing `<tag/>`. May you please elaborate to me when to use which syntax.

Examples

Case 1

```
<TextView
    android:text="Hello World"
/>
```

Case 2

```
<RelativeLayout>
    content
<RelativeLayout/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two things aren't equivalent. Between the opening and closing tags, you can have many different XML nodes of different types, but inside a tag, between the `<Name` and `/>`, you can only have XML attributes. On the other hand, attributes cannot appear outside a tag.

```
<tag attribute="value">
   <another-tag />
   <namespace:tag> <!-- comment --> <?processing instruction?> </namespace:tag>
   Text
</tag>
<closed-tag attribute="value" />
```